# split string (based on comma) into array adds an empty item at the end of list

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, split

I'm using below regex to split a string in the basis of comma into array,
which works completely fine.

```
my $string = '$n(bar,foo),  (bar),a.*$n(f04((?!z).)*)b, 
 hello$n(((((((abcdef)))))))world';

my @array;
push @array, $1 while $string =~ /
            ((?:
              [^(),]+ |
              ( \(
                (?: [^()]+ | (?2) )*
              \) )
            )*)
            (?: ,\s* | $)
            /xg;


$VAR1 = [
          '$n(bar,foo)',
          '(bar)',
          'a.*$n(f04((?!z).)*)b',
          'hello$n(((((((abcdef)))))))world',
          ''
];
```

Problem is it always adds an empty string as the last item of an array. I don't want this. Please help.

Comment: Replace [`)*)` with `)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/tzOkaj/1)

Comment: ohh damn, very small mistake. Thanks

Comment: Since you are writing a rather complicated regex, it would be useful for you and for future maintainers if you used postfix comments on each line to remind the reader of what you are trying to accomplish.  You may also try using a parser, which has already (hopefully) been debugged....

Comment: you could remove the first capturing group and have the regex like `(?:[^(),]+|(\((?:[^()]+|(?1))*\)))+(?:,\s*|$)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first capturing group contains a `*`-quantified non-capturing group, and thus can be empty. To avoid that, you need to use a `+` quantifier to make it match at least once.

```
push @array, $1 while $string =~ /
        ((?:
          [^(),]+ |
          ( \(
            (?: [^()]+ | (?2) )*
          \) )
        )+)           # < HERE
        (?: ,\s* | $)
        /xg;
```